# Using OnApplicationPause() in unity instead of onResume() in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lifecycle

Is it possible to not call onResume() and onPause() in Android instead handle that on c# in unity via OnApplicationPause() ?

when I export unity project to android I have this :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}
```

is it possible to remove 
*mUnityPlayer.resume();* and 
*mUnityPlayer.pause();*
because in my c# code I setup :

```
void OnApplicationPause (bool pauseStatus)
    {
        if (pauseStatus) {
            Debug.Log("applicationWillResignActive or onPause");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("applicationDidBecomeActive or onResume");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do mean by not call??

Comment: I mean on Android I don't call mUnityPlayer.resume()

Comment: sorry not able to understand your question here budddy

Comment: Ok let me update my question

Comment: if you're handling it somewhere else then you can remove it what's the problem??

Comment: yes ! because I was trying to handle it on c# but if I don't call mUnityPlayer.resume() on android, a black screen is displayed

Comment: share your code what you're doing when you handle it in C#

Comment: I'm only debugging . do I need to implement something ?

Comment: it'll be difficult to explain without seeing your code or without understanding your application flow

Comment: I just wanna know if it's possible to not use mUnityPlayer in Android in onResume and onPause . if yes how to do it ?

Comment: I don't know what is the flow of your application so I'll explain it in general terms. you can do it but you've to still handle onResume functionality of your unity player because once come back from onPause state android will call it's onResume method if you have some states to resume that's where you handle all those things